# Discord.py - Scanning all the Embed Fields for a specific phrase

Tags: python, discord.py

so right now I am trying to create a command which allows the user to modify their channel's details on an embed. The only problem I have here is that I need to manually specific a number for where the embed field is. Is there a way for the bot to scan through the whole embed for a specific name and return the fields position? (I have a example linked below)

```py
message = guild.get_message(63861098570842132)
embed = next(embed for embed in message.embeds)
embed.fields[0].value = "New value" #Issue Here
await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

https://gyazo.com/967101d666e78dcccef945f3c5d6e280 >Example of the embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the embed in form of a dict, loop through every field and if it's the field you want, simply change it's value. Then convert the dict to a `discord.Embed` obj and edit the message

```py
# This is the user input
user_input = {'field name': 'some name', 'field value': 'some value'}

# Getting the embed and converting it to a dict
embed = message.embeds[0]
embed_dict = embed.to_dict()

for field in embed_dict['fields']:
    if field['name'] == user_input['field name']:
        field['value'] = user_input['field value']

# Converting the embed to a `discord.Embed` obj
edited_embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict)

# Editing the message
await message.edit(embed=edited_embed)
```

Reference:

- [`discord.Embed.to_dict`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed%20to_dict#discord.Embed.to_dict)
- [`discord.Embed.from_dict`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed%20from_dict#discord.Embed.from_dict)
- [`message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20edit#discord.Message.edit)

Comment: The message is marked as edited but none of the content has changed.